When try to upload file in mobile browser it's showing all the options
I am trying to upload file on mobile browser, it's showing all three options instead of documents.
<input #file accept=".pdf, .doc, .docx" placeholder="Add a Document" id="file" type="file" multiple (change)="onfileChange($event,'document')">
it's showing  all three options instead of documents
I have tried ngb file picker and accept type
